# Retrofit and Acces token on android

Tags: android, jwt, retrofit2, access-token

I  want to do a login and i need to use jwt acces tokens

My apiService method  is like:

```
@POST("login-bus")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<String> login(@Header("Token") String token,
                   @Field("username") String username,
                   @Field("password") String password);
```

and i dont know if it is enougth ,i mean , acces token is simply a String that i have to send every time i will call the server? or is not? if is not please explain me

Comment: `Token` is your key ?

Comment: This will pass value in the request header. Do you want to pass Authorization header, right?

Comment: You can check out the approach described here: https://medium.com/@burkedamian/token-based-authentication-per-endpoint-via-http-interceptor-627b958c26b8 it allows you to exchange tokens in runtime in a centralized object, handle multiple tokens (app, user) and define via retrofit annotation which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

An access token is a token, a string value that may contain some information about the user access.
It will probably be needed in every request to server if you need to be authenticated, so, I recommend you reading [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android) to use tokens with retrofit!